# How to give iDs to dynamic fields in React-Redux?

Tags: mongodb, react-redux, frontend, backend, feathersjs

I created a simple dynamic fields in React-Redux with a plus button to add as many field as I want (hobbies) of an already existing form. I'm using mongodb as a database and so I have this error that tells me that my fields/data don't have iDs.

so how can I generate iDs for my data?

this below is my model with featherJs. as you can see this is how I added my hobbies array in the existing model called myService. I can see that my hobbies are created in mongo (using Robo 3T) which is great but i'm having difficulty reusing them (hobbies) in an other component in Redux. I'm not sure if I should give IDs to this fields or create a new service just for them. I never coded something in backend so I'm confused. what's the rule for this kind of situations.

Any other suggestions would be helpful.

warning in Redux: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

error in api : Cast to ObjectId failed for value at path "_id" for model "

```
 const { Schema } = mongooseClient;

  const myService = new Schema({
    type: { type: String, enum: VALID_TYPES, required: true },
    user: {
      type: mongooseClient.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user',
      required: true
    },
    comment: String,
    hobbies: [{
        type: mongooseClient.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'hobbies',
        default: [],
        required: false }],
    date: {
      begin: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      current: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
      end: { type: Date, required: true },
    },
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });

  return mongooseClient.model('myService', myService);
};
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code and the specific error message. Is the error coming from your api or from react?

Comment: I did, can you please help ?